# Filtering an array which controls v-for in Vue app with array.filter works with equality but not RegExp

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I would like to search in a text box and filter a list of objects by whether a property matches the entered text.

Each of the objects in the filteredBuildings array creates a shape on a Google Map.

I have the following in my Vue app:

```
...

data: {
    searchtext: '',
    buildings: [
        {
            name: 'Home',
            ...
        },{
            name: 'Work',
            ...
        }
    ],
},
computed: {
    filteredBuildings () {
        if( this.searchtext == '' )
            return this.buildings;

        const re = new RegExp( this.searchtext, 'i' );
        return this.buildings.filter( b => {
            // return b.name === this.searchtext;
            // return b.name.toLowerCase().indexOf( this.searchtext.toLowerCase() ) > -1;
            return re.test(b.name);
        });
    },
},

...
```

and the templates are complicated, but something like this:

```
// the main component
<div id="app">

    <GoogleMapPolygon v-for="b in filteredBuildings"
        :key="b.id"
        :id="b.id"
        :name="name"
        ...
    />

</div>

// the GoogleMapPolygon component
// (no <template>)
... 
data: {
    polygon: null,
    ...
},
mounted () {
    this.polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        map: map,
        ...
    });
    ...
},
destroyed () {
    this.polygon.setMap(null);
},
render () { 
    return false; 
},
```

If I uncomment the line with `===` matching, it works just fine. 
If I use either the `indexOf` matching or the `RegExp .test()`, I get the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node."

and the app completely dies.

The extra time that the `RegExp` or `indexOf` takes seems to be enough to cause the problem. That brings my thinking to `nextTick()`, but I'm not sure where I would put that.

Comment: You can log the array before it is returned to see whether it is filtering correctly. Most likely this is nothing to do with the filtering itself, it's just that whatever consumes this array isn't coping with the filtered array correctly.

Comment: That seems to make sense, except that it works fine when the filter test uses `===` instead of `RegExp` or `indexOf`

Comment: Presumably that returns a different array of items though? With `===`, I'm guessing that as you type the first character in the box it will jump from returning everything to returning nothing? Then as you keep typing it will eventually match the name of a single item? That's very different from a DOM-update scenario where you jump from showing everything to showing a large subset, such as you would with `indexOf`.

Comment: How are you attempting to use the computed value? Given this appears to be a rendering warning, what does your template look like?

Comment: @Phil Thanks for looking, I've added some of the vue template in question.

Comment: Try using an open and closing tag instead of self-closing

Comment: ... ie `<GoogleMapPolygon ...></GoogleMapPolygon>`

Comment: @Phil No good. That doesn't help. I updated the question... essentially it's a speed thing in combination with google maps

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from modifying the array of buildings (the elements which are beings used in the `v-for` directive ) too quickly. Judging by the error, Vue is using those elements as reference points to insert other array items, but reference DOM element has disappeared by the time vue tries to insert the new one.

This *could* potentially be just a problem with **Vue** interacting with **Google Maps**

Solution is to wrap the component being iterated in an element which won't go away when other parts are toggled. For example (from my original question code):

```
<div id="app">

  <section>
    <GoogleMapPolygon v-for="b in filteredBuildings"
        :key="b.id"
        :id="b.id"
        :name="name"
        ...
    />
  </section>

</div>
```

I also got this problem when removing one marker and replacing it with another just after it, and this solves that issue as well:

```
<section>
    <GoogleMapMarker 
        v-if="this.zoom > 15"
        :key="'you-are-here-marker'"
        :lat="currentLat"
        :lng="currentLng"
    />
</section>

<section>
    <GoogleMapMarker
        v-if="this.zoom < 16"
        :key="'campus-center-marker'"
        :lat="campusCenter.lat"
        :lng="campusCenter.lng"
    />
</section>
```

Before adding the section tags, I was getting the same error when these two components tried to destroy and create when `this.zoom` changed.